# ¿Cómo adquirió "pinito" su significado actual?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia

En español hay una expresión "hacer pinitos" que significa "dar los primeros pasos en algo". Para mi sorpresa, el DRAE recoge "pinito" (que yo pensaba que no lo haría al ser un diminutivo y no una palabra propia) como

> [Pinito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=T3oAKZN) **(del diminutivo de pino)**.
>
> 1. m. Cada uno de los primeros pasos que da el niño o el convaleciente. U. m. en pl. Está haciendo pinitos.
> 2. m. pl. Primeros pasos que se dan en algún arte o ciencia.

Entiendo que la segunda acepción hace clara referencia a la primera (primeros pasos o intentos de alguien que está empezando, a andar o a adquirir otra habilidad).

Dice esa entrada que "pinito" viene del diminutivo de pino, pero viendo las [entradas para "pino"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=T3vyIIP%7CT3wHEqJ), solo hay una (de cuatro) no relacionada con el árbol o su madera

> 3. m. Ejercicio gimnástico que consiste en poner el cuerpo verticalmente con los pies hacia arriba, apoyando las manos en el suelo. Hacer el pino.

Y no es que *hacer el pino* sea una proeza o habilidad baladí en comparación con dar tus primeros pasos cuando eres un bebé, pero no creo que haya demasiada relación entre "dar los primeros pasos" que suelen ser con los pies, y un ejercicio gimnástico donde los pies se ponen precisamente en lo alto (las manos en el suelo, y aunque puedes echar a andar sobre las manos, no es realmente eso lo que busca el ejercicio), y menos con el árbol o su madera.

Así que "pinito" viene del diminutivo de "pino" pero, ¿Cómo exactamente? ¿Cuál es la evolución de la etimológica de "pinito"?

Answer (score 5):

Al parecer, el árbol del pino ha sido desde antiguo sinónimo de verticalidad. Del sustantivo *pino* proviene el adjetivo:

> [**pino<sup>2</sup>, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T3wHEqJ)
>
> De *pino<sup>1</sup>*.
>
> 1. adj. Muy pendiente o muy derecho. *La cuesta del monte es muy pina.*
> 2. m. coloq. **pinito** (‖ primer paso del niño o del convaleciente). U. m. en pl. *Está haciendo pinos.*

Como ves, su significado es "muy pendiente o muy derecho". Y de hecho, de este adjetivo proviene *empinar*:

> [**empinar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EqfCV2d)
>
> De *en-* y *pino<sup>2</sup>* 'derecho'.
>
> 1. tr. Enderezar y levantar en alto.
> 2. tr. Inclinar mucho el vaso, el jarro, la bota, etc., para beber, levantando en alto la vasija.
> 3. tr. coloq. Beber mucho, especialmente vino. U. m. c. intr.
> 4. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Ponerse sobre las puntas de los pies y erguirse.
> 5. prnl. Dicho de un cuadrúpedo: Ponerse sobre las patas traseras levantando las manos.
> 6. prnl. Dicho de una planta, de una torre, de una montaña, etc.: Alcanzar gran altura.

Este verbo ya se usaba en el siglo XV:

> *Dulçe tierra que tanto amo,
>
>   do nasçe la sal rapina,
>
>   ¿quién me partió tan aína
>
>   de ti e tu señorío
>
>   e me troxo al grant río
>
>   do el sol nasçe e se empina?*
>
> Francisco Imperial, "Poesías [Cancionero de Baena]", a1409 (España).

Con toda esta información, resulta natural que cuando un niño abandona la posición de gateo y empieza a erguirse, es decir, a empinarse y a ponerse derecho y vertical, se le diga que está "empinándose", "haciéndose un pino" o, coloquialmente, haciendo pinos. Esta expresión es un poco más tardía pero se encuentra ya en textos del siglo XVI:

> *De aquí le viene que tenga menos noticia de lo que entiende que los ángeles, y que no pueda calar ni penetrar los objetos que se le presentan a los sentidos, sino que ha de ir poco a poco y como haciendo pinitos, como niño que se comienza a soltar; así ha de hacerlos el alma con el entendimiento.*
>
> Fray Pedro Malón de Chaide, "La conversión de la Magdalena", 1588 (España).

De hecho la primera referencia que he encontrado en un diccionario acerca de la expresión es en el tratado *Origen y etimología de todos los vocablos originales de la lengua castellana* del doctor Francisco del Rosal, de 1611 (Covarrubias me ha fallado en esta ocasión):

> **Pino**, arbol, asi se lama el Latino, como *Pítyno*, del Griego que le llama *Pitys*. Pero *Pino*, ò *Pinico*, que hacen los niños. B. Empinar.